# How to *actually* read CSV data in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

I'm relatively new to the world of TensorFlow, and pretty perplexed by how you'd ***actually*** read CSV data into a usable example/label tensors in TensorFlow. The example from the [TensorFlow tutorial on reading CSV data](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#reading-from-files) is pretty fragmented and only gets you part of the way to being able to train on CSV data.

Here's my code that I've pieced together, based off that CSV tutorial:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf

def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

filename = "csv_test_data.csv"

# setup text reader
file_length = file_len(filename)
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename])
reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
_, csv_row = reader.read(filename_queue)

# setup CSV decoding
record_defaults = [[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 = tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=record_defaults)

# turn features back into a tensor
features = tf.stack([col1,col2,col3,col4])

print("loading, " + str(file_length) + " line(s)\n")
with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

  # start populating filename queue
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  for i in range(file_length):
    # retrieve a single instance
    example, label = sess.run([features, col5])
    print(example, label)

  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
  print("\ndone loading")
```

And here is an brief example from the CSV file I'm loading - pretty basic data - 4 feature columns, and 1 label column:

```
0,0,0,0,0
0,15,0,0,0
0,30,0,0,0
0,45,0,0,0
```

All the code above does is **print each example from the CSV file, one by one**, which, while nice, is pretty darn useless for training.

What I'm struggling with here is how you'd actually turn those individual examples, loaded one-by-one, into a training dataset. For example, [here's a notebook](https://github.com/rringham/deep-learning-notebooks/blob/master/notMNIST_four_hidden_layers.ipynb) I was working on in the Udacity Deep Learning course. I basically want to take the CSV data I'm loading, and plop it into something like **train_dataset** and **train_labels**:

```
def reformat(dataset, labels):
  dataset = dataset.reshape((-1, image_size * image_size)).astype(np.float32)
  # Map 2 to [0.0, 1.0, 0.0 ...], 3 to [0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ...]
  labels = (np.arange(num_labels) == labels[:,None]).astype(np.float32)
  return dataset, labels
train_dataset, train_labels = reformat(train_dataset, train_labels)
valid_dataset, valid_labels = reformat(valid_dataset, valid_labels)
test_dataset, test_labels = reformat(test_dataset, test_labels)
print('Training set', train_dataset.shape, train_labels.shape)
print('Validation set', valid_dataset.shape, valid_labels.shape)
print('Test set', test_dataset.shape, test_labels.shape)
```

I've tried using `tf.train.shuffle_batch`, like this, but it just inexplicably hangs:

```
  for i in range(file_length):
    # retrieve a single instance
    example, label = sess.run([features, colRelevant])
    example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([example, label], batch_size=file_length, capacity=file_length, min_after_dequeue=10000)
    print(example, label)
```

So to sum up, here are my questions:

- **What am I missing about this process?**

  - It feels like there is some key intuition that I'm missing about how to properly build an input pipeline.
- **Is there a way to avoid having to know the length of the CSV file?**

  - It feels pretty inelegant to have to know the number of lines you want to process (the `for i in range(file_length)` line of code above)

---

**Edit:**
As soon as Yaroslav pointed out that I was likely mixing up imperative and graph-construction parts here, it started to become clearer. I was able to pull together the following code, which I think is closer to what would typically done when training a model from CSV (excluding any model training code):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import math as math
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('dataset')
args = parser.parse_args()

def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

def read_from_csv(filename_queue):
  reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
  _, csv_row = reader.read(filename_queue)
  record_defaults = [[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]
  colHour,colQuarter,colAction,colUser,colLabel = tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=record_defaults)
  features = tf.stack([colHour,colQuarter,colAction,colUser])  
  label = tf.stack([colLabel])  
  return features, label

def input_pipeline(batch_size, num_epochs=None):
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([args.dataset], num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)  
  example, label = read_from_csv(filename_queue)
  min_after_dequeue = 10000
  capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
  example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
      [example, label], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
      min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
  return example_batch, label_batch

file_length = file_len(args.dataset) - 1
examples, labels = input_pipeline(file_length, 1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

  # start populating filename queue
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  try:
    while not coord.should_stop():
      example_batch, label_batch = sess.run([examples, labels])
      print(example_batch)
  except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print('Done training, epoch reached')
  finally:
    coord.request_stop()

  coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: I've been trying out your code, but can't get it to work. Is there something I'm missing that you determined? Thanks. I've posted a thread here so you can get more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143019/how-to-correctly-read-data-from-csvs-into-tensorflow

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you are mixing up imperative and graph-construction parts here. The operation `tf.train.shuffle_batch` creates a new queue node, and a single node can be used to process the entire dataset. So I think you are hanging because you created a bunch of `shuffle_batch` queues in your for loop and didn't start queue runners for them.

Normal input pipeline usage looks like this:

1. Add nodes like `shuffle_batch` to input pipeline
2. (optional, to prevent unintentional graph modification) finalize graph

--- end of graph construction, beginning of imperative programming --

3. `tf.start_queue_runners`
4. `while(True): session.run()`

To be more scalable (to avoid Python GIL), you could generate all of your data using TensorFlow pipeline. However, if performance is not critical, you can hook up a numpy array to an input pipeline by using `slice_input_producer.` Here's an example with some `Print` nodes to see what's going on (messages in `Print` go to stdout when node is run)

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

num_examples = 5
num_features = 2
data = np.reshape(np.arange(num_examples*num_features), (num_examples, num_features))
print data

(data_node,) = tf.slice_input_producer([tf.constant(data)], num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
data_node_debug = tf.Print(data_node, [data_node], "Dequeueing from data_node ")
data_batch = tf.batch([data_node_debug], batch_size=2)
data_batch_debug = tf.Print(data_batch, [data_batch], "Dequeueing from data_batch ")

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
tf.get_default_graph().finalize()
tf.start_queue_runners()

try:
  while True:
    print sess.run(data_batch_debug)
except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError as e:
  print "No more inputs."
```

You should see something like this

```
[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]
 [6 7]
 [8 9]]
[[0 1]
 [2 3]]
[[4 5]
 [6 7]]
No more inputs.
```

The "8, 9" numbers didn't fill up the full batch, so they didn't get produced. Also `tf.Print` are printed to sys.stdout, so they show up in separately in Terminal for me.

PS: a minimal of connecting `batch` to a manually initialized queue is in [github issue 2193](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2193)

Also, for debugging purposes you might want to set `timeout` on your session so that your IPython notebook doesn't hang on empty queue dequeues. I use this helper function for my sessions

```
def create_session():
  config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)
  config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.3 # don't hog all vRAM
  config.operation_timeout_in_ms=60000   # terminate on long hangs
  # create interactive session to register a default session
  sess = tf.InteractiveSession("", config=config)
  return sess
```

Scalability Notes:

1. `tf.constant` inlines copy of your data into the Graph. There's a fundamental limit of 2GB on size of Graph definition so that's an upper limit on size of data
2. You could get around that limit by using `v=tf.Variable` and saving the data into there by running `v.assign_op` with a `tf.placeholder` on right-hand side and feeding numpy array to the placeholder (`feed_dict`)
3. That still creates two copies of data, so to save memory  you could make your own version of `slice_input_producer` which operates on numpy arrays, and uploads rows one at a time using `feed_dict`

Comment: Ahh, yes! You are totally right - as soon as you said: "I think you are mixing up imperative and graph-construction parts here", I started to see where I was going wrong. I've posted an edit to my question that includes the latest code I put together, which actually gets me closer to what I want - I'm able to successfully read in CSV data and batch it in such a way that I could train a model.

Comment: I suggest updating this answer so it works with recent versions of TensorFlow: replace `tf.slice_input_producer()` with `tf.train.slice_input_producer()` (and similarly for several other functions).  And also add `sess.run(tf.initialize_local_variables())` after `sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())`.

Comment: Some more changes to make: `pack()` is now `stack()`, and `initialize_all_variables()` should be replaced with `global_variables_initializer()` and `local_variables_initializer()`.

Comment: With tensorflow 1.0.1 you need to initialize local and global variables as `tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()).run()`. 
You will need to initialize local variables since you are using num_epochs and as per [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/string_input_producer#tftrainstring_input_producerstring_tensor_num_epochsnone_shuffletrue_seednone_capacity32_shared_namenone_namenone_cancel_opnone_1) _"Note: if `num_epochs` is not `None`, this function creates local counter
  `epochs`."_

Answer (score 13):

Or you could try this, the code loads the Iris dataset into tensorflow using pandas and numpy and a simple one neuron output is printed in the session. Hope it helps for a basic understanding.... [ I havent added the way of one hot decoding labels].

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('/home/nagarjun/Desktop/Iris.csv',usecols = [0,1,2,3,4],skiprows = [0],header=None)
d = df.values
l = pd.read_csv('/home/nagarjun/Desktop/Iris.csv',usecols = [5] ,header=None)
labels = l.values
data = numpy.float32(d)
labels = numpy.array(l,'str')
#print data, labels

#tensorflow
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(150,5))
x = data
w = tf.random_normal([100,150],mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(w,x))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(y)
```

Comment: This was very instructive, but if I understand correctly it does not show how to use the data for training...

Comment: yes, i'll add them soon... It should be trivial isn't it.... calculate the loss, run the optimizer anaway i'll add them soon

Comment: Hi dividebyzero, sorry i'm late ! I found another link which is interesting and really eases the problem https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/tflearn/.... Here you can load the csv files, train them, perform classification...

Comment: @NagarjunGururaj Can I use the dataset constructed by the contrib_learn in the normal tensorflow routine?

Comment: which dataset ? You mean Iris or any other ?

Comment: @Nagarjun Gururaj Why did you use `labels = l.values` here ? what is the use of this line?

Comment: @WiLL_K first i get the values of last column or 5th column and then convert it to string using labels variable

Answer (score 2):

You can use latest tf.data API :

```
dataset = tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset(filepath)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
columns = iterator.get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run([iteator.initializer])
```

Comment: How does this code know which column is the training label?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone came here searching for a simple way to read absolutely large and sharded CSV files in tf.estimator API then , please see below my code

```
CSV_COLUMNS = ['ID','text','class']
LABEL_COLUMN = 'class'
DEFAULTS = [['x'],['no'],[0]]  #Default values

def read_dataset(filename, mode, batch_size = 512):
    def _input_fn(v_test=False):
#         def decode_csv(value_column):
#             columns = tf.decode_csv(value_column, record_defaults = DEFAULTS)
#             features = dict(zip(CSV_COLUMNS, columns))
#             label = features.pop(LABEL_COLUMN)
#             return add_engineered(features), label

        # Create list of files that match pattern
        file_list = tf.gfile.Glob(filename)

        # Create dataset from file list
        #dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(file_list).map(decode_csv)
        dataset = tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset(file_list,
                                                   batch_size=batch_size,
                                                   column_names=CSV_COLUMNS,
                                                   column_defaults=DEFAULTS,
                                                   label_name=LABEL_COLUMN)

        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
            num_epochs = None # indefinitely
            dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size = 10 * batch_size)
        else:
            num_epochs = 1 # end-of-input after this

        batch_features, batch_labels = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

        #Begins - Uncomment for testing only -----------------------------------------------------<
        if v_test == True:
            with tf.Session() as sess:
                print(sess.run(batch_features))
        #End - Uncomment for testing only -----------------------------------------------------<
        return add_engineered(batch_features), batch_labels
    return _input_fn
```

Example usage in TF.estimator:

```
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn = read_dataset(
                                                filename = train_file,
                                                mode = tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN,
                                                batch_size = 128), 
                                      max_steps = num_train_steps)
```