# How to get CSV data into TensorFlow

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

I've recently started to get into Deep Learning with Tensor Flow. I've read a lot of online resources and took a Udacity course for beginners. I gained a lot of the basic principles of Deep Learning. But one thing I am struggling right now wasn't the topic of any of these resources. I have no idea how I can get my own labeled data (CSV format) into my Python program to train my net on. I've came across [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143019/how-to-correctly-read-data-from-csvs-into-tensorflow) and started to implement the Input Pipe in the way the post showed and it worked so far. When I tried to train my model by feeding my **features** and **labels** with

```
sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={
        x: features,
        y: labels,
    })
```

TF is throwing an error

```
TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.
```

X and Y are defined as placeholders and the session is calling **tf.global_variables_initializer()**

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[10, batch_size])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
```

But the objects returned by **tf.train.shuffle_batch** are Tensors right? Should/can I convert them back to valid data type like a Numpy Array or is there any other, more efficient way of reading my data.

Comment: Did my answer solved the issue ??

Comment: @hars Yes the first approach works now. I tried your second solution, but I'm not exactly sure how this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways.

1. **With feed_dict** :

   ```
   features_numpy,labels_numpy = sess.run([features,labels])
   sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={ x: features_numpy,y: labels_numpy})
   ```

   Run the session, get numpy values for features and labels and feed it to the model using feed_dict. But this is inefficient because you're copying TF data to Numpy and feeding it to TF again. Follow **2** for efficient way.
2. **Avoid feed_fict**

   Do not use feed_dict and placeholders. Directly connect features and labels node to model. Or do this

   ```
   x = features
   y = labels
   ```

   Do *sess.run(model_output/loss/accuracy)* to get predictions or train the model.

I hope this helps.