# How to read dataset names from string tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow, I have a tensor(string type) in which I have stored image paths of all the required images that i want to use for training a model.

*Question : How to read the tensor to queue and then batch it.*

My Approach is: Is giving me error

```
    img_names = dataset['f0']
    file_length = len(img_names)
    type(img_names)
    tf_img_names = tf.stack(img_names)
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf_img_names, num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=False)
    wd=getcwd()
    print('In input pipeline')
    tf_img_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(file_length,dtypes=[tf.string])
    col_Image = tf_img_queue.dequeue(filename_queue)
    ### Read Image
    img_file = tf.read_file(wd+'/'+col_Image)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(img_file, channels=num_channels)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.
    image = tf.image.resize_images(image,[image_width, image_height])
    min_after_dequeue = 100
    capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
    image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch([image, onehot], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity, allow_smaller_final_batch = True, min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
```

Error : *TypeError: expected string or buffer'*

I dont know if my approach is right or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create another Queue. You can define a reader that will dequeue elements for you.  You can try the following and comment how that goes.

```
reader = tf.IdentityReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
dir = tf.constant(wd)
path = tf.string_join([dir,tf.constant("/"),value])
img_file = tf.read_file(path)
```

and to check you're feeding correct paths, do

```
print(sess.run(img_file))
```

Looking for your feedback.

Comment: what if I have read a csv file using numpy `genfromtxt` like 

`csv_file = np.genfromtxt(args.dataset, delimiter=',',skip_header=1,usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,5), dtype=None)`

how to use string_input_producer to queue and batch the files....

Comment: You don't have to use numpy reading. Use tf.TextLineReader() and parse each line to what you need and load images. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091899/how-to-actually-read-csv-data-in-tensorflow