# How to read data from csv file in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

May I get sample code to read data from csv.
My Requirement is I need to generate Train and test data from CSV in TensorFlow.

one CSV that contains both Train and Test data . I mean first 10 rows I take for Train and next 10 for test 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \*actually\* read CSV data in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091899/how-to-actually-read-csv-data-in-tensorflow)

Comment: How are the columns distributed in your csv's? How many csv's you are talking about (one with both train/test or separated)?

Comment: one CSV that contains both Train and Test data . I mean first 10 rows I take for Train and next 10 for test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folks at TensorFlow have created an [excellent tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide) that does just this. It covers how to read the census data from csv, convert it into tensors, and fit and evaluate a machine learning model using the high-level estimator API.

However, I did get an error when I tried using the `urllib` function, and I modified the code slightly so that the data is read directly using `pandas`.

**Original Code**

```
import tempfile
import urllib
train_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
test_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
urllib.urlretrieve("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data", train_file.name)
urllib.urlretrieve("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.test", test_file.name)

import pandas as pd
CSV_COLUMNS = [
    "age", "workclass", "fnlwgt", "education", "education_num",
    "marital_status", "occupation", "relationship", "race", "gender",
    "capital_gain", "capital_loss", "hours_per_week", "native_country",
    "income_bracket"]
df_train = pd.read_csv(train_file.name, names=CSV_COLUMNS, skipinitialspace=True)
df_test = pd.read_csv(test_file.name, names=CSV_COLUMNS, skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=1)
```

**Modified code**

```
import pandas as pd
COLUMNS = ["age", "workclass", "fnlwgt", "education", "education_num",
           "marital_status", "occupation", "relationship", "race", "gender",
           "capital_gain", "capital_loss", "hours_per_week", "native_country",
           "income_bracket"]

df_train = pd.read_csv('http://mlr.cs.umass.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data'
                       , names=COLUMNS
                       , skipinitialspace=True)
df_test = pd.read_csv('http://mlr.cs.umass.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.test'
                      , names=COLUMNS
                      , skipinitialspace=True
                      , skiprows=1)
```